# Synaptics Parameter Settings Not Working: PalmDetect

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I've tried to enable PalmDetect on my touchpad using the synclient command but it doesnt work. I've even reduced PalmMinWidth=1, which should have rendered the touchpad virtually useless.

Can anybody offer some help?

```
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 FocalTech FocalTech Touchpad         id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Answer (score 3):

To make change permament and if no syndaemon is installed.

edit existing 50-synaptics.conf
under /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

If the file is not available copy it from /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d and make the directories in /etc/X11 if not present.

```
 Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is re0commend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be 
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "PalmDetect" "1"
        Option "PalmMinWidth" "4"
        Option "PalmMinZ" "100"
EndSection
```

The change in Palm detection will become permanent.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your touchpad does not report pressure.

First of all check if palm detection is on

```
synclient PalmDetect=1
```

If that does not work you can set pressure threshold to 0.

```
synclient PalmMinZ=0
```

But together with `PalmMinWidth=1` it may disable touchpad. Consider a higher value.

You can check your touchpad oalm detection parameters with

```
xinput list-props <id>
```

where  is the touchpad id from `xinput` command.

You have a Focaltech touchpad. I was the author of [the patch](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/input/mouse/focaltech.c?id=85919a00e55f90e72405e707eb23c930b8d8db91) that reports finger width to user space. It has been applied to kernel 4.2.
But if you use a driver from [my ppa](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/focaltech-dkms), it is included there.

The correct command is `synclient PalmDetect=1 PalmMinZ=0 PalmMinWidth=N`

Where `N` is a value between 1 and 7. If you use a value higher than 7, it will be set to hardware default. Maximum accepted value is 15.

Comment: It started mysteriously working after installing Guake Terminal and Unity Tweak Tool.  Not sure why, unless installing tweak tool fixed some kind of synaptics dependency or something.            Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I updated my answer. @JdPartridge

Comment: And also you can use `syndaemon` to disable the touchpad while typing. You can set higher timeout there, but you need to disable the same feature in System Settings, or there will be a conflict.

Comment: Thanks Pilot6. Where should I save them? /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf ?